# MySQL database - optimizing same multiple fields

Tags: mysql, optimization, field

Recently i have created an achievement system which sets a field like `achievement1` to int 1 when something is a achieved, the problem is that we have over a 100 fields that go `achievement1`, `achievement2`, `achievement3` and so on...

So my question is how do i optimize this ? I was thinking about storing a string in one field that would be like `1,0,1,0,1,0,1...` 0 for unachieved achievements and 1 for completed. But would that not be worse since i'd have to update a very long string everytime instead of 1 integer ?

I've looked for an answer everywhere but i found nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table that stores achievements for each user (assuming that they are related to a user in some way). There could be a foreign key for the UserID and then an integer value for the achievement number. So (15,1) would indicate that the user with the ID of 15 has completed Achievement1. If you wanted to find all the achievements that a user has completed, just do something like:

`SELECT achievementNumber FROM tblAchievements WHERE UserID = 15`.

The text for "achievement" is really arbitrary, it's how you use it that matters.

Comment: So something like this ? [link]http://www.part.lt/img/f8e2c5b3692175f3dacd5b4e105bce7b549.png (uzduotys means achievements)

Cause i've already done this, i'm now looking for a more optimized way of doing this if it's actually possible ?

Comment: More like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Nzqk8/ You would only have two columns in the table. One for the user that the achievement is for, and one for the number of the achievement.